# Use Excel VBA to bulk download images with directory structure

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Save_image()
Dim oHTTP As Object
Dim sDestFolder As String
Dim sSrcUrl As String
Dim sImageFile As String

sDestFolder = "C:\Users\adale\Desktop\Compendium Images\"
sSrcUrl = ActiveCell.Value
If Left(sSrcUrl, 2) = "//" Then
    sSrcUrl = "http:" & sSrcUrl
End If

sImageFile = Right(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - InStrRev(ActiveCell.Value, "/"))
Debug.Print sImageFile
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = sImageFile


Set oHTTP = CreateObject("msxml2.XMLHTTP")
oHTTP.Open "GET", sSrcUrl, False
oHTTP.send

Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
oStream.Type = adTypeBinary
oStream.Open

oStream.write oHTTP.responseBody
oStream.savetofile sDestFolder & sImageFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite

Set oStream = Nothing
Set oHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sourced the above code from: http://tipsformarketers.com/use-excel-to-download-hundreds-of-images-instantly/

I have an Excel sheet with 3 columns all containing URLs to images, see example image attached: [image]

What VBA routine could handle running through each column, downloading the image to the local computer (PC) whilst also creating/maintaining the directory structure, e.g. creating local nested folders: /wp-content/uploads/XXXX/XX/file_name.jpg.

Comment: Cool, and what have you already done?

Comment: Hi @VictorMoraes - I've just resorted to putting all the URLs in to a single column to make life easier for myself. Walk before I run! The problem right now is not being able to re-create the folder structure locally - the code from the link in my OP works, but sticks them in a single folder.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to post the code you are using instead of a link to it? The link might be unavailable in the future, not to mention you will receive more replies if you post *your* actual work, instead of just a reference. It would also be nice to post a screenshot of your current table, since you changed it ;)